Python Plot Colorbar For Contour Plot
I have the following code that generates a plot:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

data = xr.open_dataset('mypath/data.nc')  

lat=np.array(data['latitude'][:])
lon=np.array(data['longitude'][:])
u = np.array(data['u'][:])
u = u.reshape(len(lat),len(lon))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8, 6))
X,Y=np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
ax.contourf(X,Y,u)

Python Plot
How can I add a colorbar?
I tried plt.colorbar().

Try the solutions proposed here and see if it works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144381/matplotlib-contour-map-colorbar

You state that you used plt.colorbar(), so also give us the exact code you used and the respective error message. This way everyone can help you best!

To add a colorbar to your plot, you can assign the result of the ax.contourf call to a variable and then pass that variable to plt.colorbar(). Here’s how you can modify your code:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 6))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
contour = ax.contourf(X, Y, u)
plt.colorbar(contour)

plt.show()

